Do flourescent tube lights create magnetic fields like other conductors?
So, does every electron flow also have a corresponding magnetic field to go along with it, or is magnetic fields only a property of solid metal conductors?
Also, what about lightning?

Magnetic fields from current flow don't care how the charges are moving. So, yes, fluorescent tube lights have weak (ac) magnetic fields.
